# Best way to split integers in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, integer

If I have this:

```
int toSplit = 208;
```

What's the best way to split it so I get:

```
2
0
8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method would be like this

```
- (NSMutableArray *) toCharArray : (NSString *) str
{

    NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[str length]];
    for (int i=0; i < [str length]; i++)
    {
        NSString *ichar  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [str characterAtIndex:i]];
        [characters addObject:ichar];
    }

    return characters;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Just a question, I will be performing this fairly regularly...is this an efficient enough way to do it?

Comment: Yes, just make a method to do it for you, will amend answer

Answer (score 2):

```
do {
  int digit = toSplit % 10;
  toSplit /= 10;

  printf(@"%i", digit);

} while (toSplit > 0);
```

I hope it's not a homework.

EDIT: it's backwards so it's not a valid answer... However, leaving it here because it can still be useful for others.

Comment: Aha don't worry it's not homework. I was using this method at first and saw that I had to reverse the array..so I was wondering if there are any better ways to do this. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sort it into a string then pull it apart. So like this:

```
int toSplit = 208;

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", toSplit];

NSMutableString *splitApartString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {

    NSString *substring = [string substringFromIndex: i];  

    [splitApartString appendFormat: @"%@\n", substring];  
}

NSLog(@"%@", splitApartString); //YAY!
```

So what this does, is puts this int into a string, splits it apart, then iterates through each character and gets a string out of that character. Then it appends that substring to a NEW string.

Another alternative, is instead of getting a substring just get the char and use the `%c` operator. Also if you take a look at this code you will see this output:

```
> 2

> 0

> 8

> // extra space here
```

You could just add a condition to check if `i` is the string length - 1 and not add a space or you could just remove the last character!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Objective-C syntax, but something like:

```
void split(int toSplit)
{ 
    if (!toSplit)
    {
        return;
    }
    split(toSplit / 10);
    int digit = toSplit % 10;
    printf(@"%i", digit);
}
```